# Baudrate of DS18B20

Tags: uart, baudrate, beaglebone-black

I'm trying to connect a DS18B20 to my Beaglebone Black. Now I wan't to determine the Baudrate but can't find it in the Datasheet of the DS18B20.

In the internet I saw different ones (9600, 19200). Can I simply choose one the Sensor pick's up on it? If so up to what maximal rate?

Sorry for this RTFM question, but I really can't find the answer for that.

Comment: Are you trying to interface it to a UART? The 1-wire protocol is significantly different and while I believe you can fudge it with a UART it's not the usual way you'd interface to one.

Comment: @PeterJ. I'm pretty new to this whole stuff. I use the serialib library. Is there a better/easier way to access it using c/c++? I didn't find any library at maxim integrated. Any help would be greatly apretiated

Comment: I've never used 1-wire from a Linux based system, but maybe take a look at http://owfs.org/. But hopefully someone has a better idea how to get it running, just using serial ports is a fairly roundabout way that might not be reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't normally connect 1-wire devices to UARTs. So you don't need to set a baud-rate.

See [Beaglebone Black 1-wire](http://blog.sarine.nl/blog/2013/08/09/beaglebone-black-getting-w1-bus-to-work/) or [ditto with Arch Linux](http://kvurd.github.io/blog/1-wire-temperature-on-the-beaglebone-black-with-arch-linux-arm/)

As an aside, 1-wire support is standard in the Raspian OS used on the Raspberry pi, it seems somewhat easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm right now trying to make it run but have some problems to load the overlay. It say's that I can't find the file (I did use capemgr.9 since .8 is not there(I'm using Ubuntu on it))

Comment: Now I finally made it run. Starting on this route would have saved me some headache... Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The timing of the DS18B20 is a lot more complex than a UART. With UART you specify a bitrate of for instance 9600 bits per second and you know each bit will be 104 us. That's the only number you need.

On pages 15 ff. of the [datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) the timing of the DS18B20 is explained. For instance

> During the initialization sequence the bus master transmits (TX) the reset pulse by pulling the 1-Wire bus low for a minimum of 480μs. The bus master then releases the bus and goes into receive mode (RX). When the bus is released, the 5kΩ pullup resistor pulls the 1-Wire bus high. When the DS18B20 detects this rising edge, it waits 15μs to 60μs and then transmits a presence pulse by pulling the 1-Wire bus low for 60μs to 240μs.

You get similar prose for read and write times.